# Is it still considered a bad practice to use cursor in sql?

Tags: sql, cursor

I've read some articles about cursors in sql and most of them says that it eats up a lot of memory and etc., but that was long ago, like 2008 or so? I want to know if is cursor still considered a bad practice up to now?

Comment: It depends on **what concrete RDBMS** you're talking about. Some absolutely need cursors - others have ways around them. You cannot answer this on a generic "SQL standard" way - it's way too dependent on the concrete vendor/product you're using

Answer (score 3):

Bad practice?  Good practice?

As with many aspects of many different languages, cursors have both positives and negatives.  As a general rule, cursors make it much more difficult to optimize queries.  So, if a query can be expressed as a set-based query, then it should be.

However, under many circumstances, cursors are necessary.  There is no reasonable alternative and they are a bona fide, powerful part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much a cursor is bad practice (it quite often is!). Sometimes using cursors is a valid solution to a problem.

It's more to do with thinking procedurally is generally not as efficient as thinking in terms of sets and joins.

The classic example of this is termed 'N + 1' in the ORM world: this refers to making 1 query to get (say) a list of IDs and then N further queries to retrieve the rows for those IDs. This can often be done as a single join query.

If you find yourself solving a problem using a cursor(s), stop for a moment and consider whether it could be done in a set based manner.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN:Cursor Implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189546.aspx)

> Using a cursor is less efficient than
>   using a default result set. In a
>   default result set the only packet
>   sent from the client to the server is
>   the packet containing the statement to
>   execute. When using a server cursor,
>   each FETCH statement must be sent from
>   the client to the server, where it
>   must be parsed and compiled into an
>   execution plan.
>
> If a Transact-SQL statement will
>   return a relatively small result set
>   that can be cached in the memory
>   available to the client application,
>   and you know before executing the
>   statement that you must retrieve the
>   entire result set, use a default
>   result set. Use server cursors only
>   when cursor operations are required to
>   support the functionality of the
>   application, or when only part of the
>   result set is likely to be retrieved.

Cursor comes with both positive and side effects, if you use them for what they're designed for, we can't said that it is actually a bad practices.